# binding data from JSON object with knockoutjs - Asp.net MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a problem to get data from returning JSON in case of nested JSON objects.

**HTML** code looks like:

```
<div>
    <h2>List Employee</h2>
    <br />
    <table class="table table-bordered" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Age</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Employees">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: Id"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: Age"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

then **KnockoutJS**

```
function ProductViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Employees = ko.observableArray();`

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetEmployee',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            self.Employees(ko.mapping.fromJS(data));
        }
    })
} 
var viewModel = new ProductViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`
```

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetEmployee()
{
    var employee = db.Employee.ToList();
    return Json(new { data = employee }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Json Object:**

```
`{"data":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Andrew","Age":25},{"Id":2,"Name":"John","Age":28},{"Id":3,"Name":"Layla","Age":24},{"Id":4,"Name":"Mia","Age":26}]}`
```

**Result Error:**

[image: Result Error]

Anybody can improve my Code, please...

Comment: @Phong, thanks for edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` is in object so you have to parse it:

```
const myData = JSON.parse(data);
self.Employees(ko.mapping.fromJS(myData.data)); //in data is your array
```

If you need data only for display you can do it without mapping: `self.Employees(myData.data);`